# Angular Typescript looping through array of objects to find the count

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I need help not sure what I'm missing. I am trying to loop through an array of objects in Angular to find count of a specific field in objects. For instance I want to find out how many ID's came in with the risk of 'Moderate', 'High','Low'?

I can count the total amount of objects for having trouble counting the number of risks associated with a type of risk like 'Moderate'

**json:**

```
[ 
{"id": 1, 
 "risk": "Moderate"
},
{"id": 2, 
 "risk": "Low"
},

{"id": 3, 
 "risk": "Moderate"
},
{"id": 4, 
 "risk": "High"
}]
```

**component.ts**

```
countTotalChanges() {
    let count = 0; 

        for (var i = 0; i < this.changeService.length; i++) {
            count++; 
    }
    return count;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
{{countTotalChanges()}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that array of objects is called `items`, for example, this will work:

```
items.filter(item => item.risk === 'Moderate').length
```

You can replace `'Moderate'` with whichever risk type you want.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. Where would that be implemented?

Comment: In whichever function you're using to count the items based on risk type. So a function could be `countItemsByRiskType(riskType: string) { ... }` and in that function is where you use my above answer. Then, from my original answer, replace `'Moderate'` with the variable `riskType`. Then you can call the function and pass in the `riskType` you want to count.